# master-workers implementation in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to implement the prototype for my application in Python and stuck on choosing libraries, frameworks...

The application is a master-workers application (event loop?), where workers requests a master about a work they should do and respond to master with the result of their work.
All tasks (works) are stored in PostgreSQL table, and only master can access its data. The table looks like:

```
task(task_id int, status varchar, length int, error_msg varchar)
```

Master process should have the following API methods to outer world (REST/HTTP):

- `get_workers_count`: retutns number of workers. When it starts first time, the initial number of workers is 0
- `set_workers(workers_count)`: sets new count of workers. If new count is greater than current one, master should spawn new workers. If new count is less then current one, some workers should die after they complete current work
- `add_task(time)`: Adds a tsak in task table with status 'READY' and length equals to time

Master process should also have the following API methods to workers (should not be acceptable to outer world):

- `get_task` Returns task_id and length of the first record in task table in status 'READY'. After returning to worker it changes the status to 'EXECUTING'. Returns -1 if there are no tasks to execute. Returns -2 if worker should die.
- `set_task_status (task_id, status)` - sets task status

Worker process should be run by master process and works as follows:

- calls `get_task method` of master. If it gets -2 it terminates. If it gets -1, it sleeps and calls get_task_again
- if it gets positive task numbert, ot sleeps for `length` of seconds (simulate work) and responds with a status (SUCCESS for prototype).

I am new in Python and ask somebody to help me in choosing frameworks/libraries for my application. My current state is:

- I want to use Flask/gunicorn for REST Api in master process
- I have no idea what to use for communication between master/worker processes. Is SocketServer is a good choice for me?
- almost all work by worker process will be performed by C extension module

  ### - workers and master will work on a single machine
- I have no idea how to start workers: should I spawn thread/greenlet or should I fork a new process?

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

ASync is probably your best bet, I personally LOVE gevent.  You could look at GIPC which multi processes gevent and gives you a read write channel back and forth.  Or you can just have them communicate over restAPI's.

Personally I would fire up two distinct processes, a master channel that manages the pool and handles the queues.  Then I would have worker processes poke at the API for new work, and when they retrieve the work they go do their business in a separate thread.

The advantage of this would be when you want to split the workers to other machines (micro computers) the only change required is an ip address.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Never heard about GIPC, will check it.

Comment: But honestly, a simple web framework `bottle` and a quick REST API would be the better solution.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean replace Flask with bottle? Or using bottle as a tool for communicating between master and workers?

Comment: Oh Sorry, no Flask works as well.  I just like the flexibility with bottle, but it's a preference.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about master/worker architecture, but you can use [pika/RabbitMQ](https://habr.com/ru/post/434510/) + [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) for event handling and task queues.

Consider RabbitMQ instead of Postgres for events - [see some discussion here](https://habr.com/ru/post/269347/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I cannot replace Postgres with RabbitMQ due to architectural issues. Will consider using RabbitMQ/pika as an additional component